# Using jQuery .on function

Tags: jquery

I have an understanding of what the .on function does as far "defining" functions/callbacks once an element is added to the DOM.

My question is, I want to automatically FIRE an event when the element is added to the DOM.

Here's the scenario: First off, I am using AJAX to load my pages, so DOM isReady() does not help me.

User clicks link and a function is fired off with a parameter that does:

- create a series of images on a page; defines the onClick event for each image
- I then look for one of those elements and performs click() event

Problem is, the second function fires too quickly. What I want to do is WAIT for the first function to complete entirely - i.e. wait for all the elements to be created, and THEN fire the click()

I see that the now retired(?) plugin LIVEQUERY used to do that.

> Live Query also has the ability to fire a function (callback) when it
>   matches a  new element and another function (callback) for when an
>   element is no longer matched.

Is there a way to do this this with the new version(s) of jQuery?

Again, I simply want to wait until an element is added to the DOM and then trigger an event on that element.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a built-in jQuery way to do it, you would have to either extend jQuery and/or using DOMMutation Events.

Comment: could you post your callback function so we can see why is not working properly?

Answer (score 4):

It's safe to assume that when the last image loads, everything else has too.

Try using the `img`'s `onload` event. It'll be called when the image has finished loading which will be after your elements have been created.